# What happens if a Muggle tries to get into Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

There is a long explanation in Harry Potter about how well protected Hogwarts castle is, but I am not sure whether or not it says what would happen if, despite all of the warnings, a non-magical human did try and get into hogwarts. I know that something happens to them, but does it specify what?

As a massive Harry Potter fan, this has been puzzling me for ages and I thought that there must be an answer! Do you know? If you do then I will be very grateful and impressed! Thanks!

Comment: Semi-dupe of [Could a squib go to Hogwarts?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69257/could-a-squib-go-to-hogwarts)

Comment: Semi-dupe of [Is there any way to tell a difference between a Squib and a Muggle?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103901/is-there-any-way-to-tell-a-difference-between-a-squib-and-a-muggle/152185#152185)

Comment: Semi-dupe of [Do Muggle Parents Visit Their Muggleborn Children at Hogwarts? Are They Totally Excluded?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18383/do-muggle-parents-visit-their-muggleborn-children-at-hogwarts-are-they-totally) which mentions at least one occasion in which muggle/s came to Hogwarts, albeit at the invitation of Dumbledore.

Answer (score 7):

One assumes that Hogwarts has a [muggle-repelling charm](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Muggle-Repelling_Charm#cite_note-DH14-0) cast upon it.

> *‘But Hogwarts is hidden,’ said Hermione, in surprise, ‘everyone knows that … well, everyone who’s read Hogwarts: A History, anyway.’
>
>   ‘Just you, then,’ said Ron. ‘So go on – how d’you hide a place like Hogwarts?’
>   ‘It’s bewitched,’ said Hermione. ‘If a Muggle looks at it, all they see is a mouldering old ruin with a sign over the entrance saying DANGER, DO NOT ENTER, UNSAFE.’
>
>   ‘So Durmstrang’ll just look like a ruin to an outsider, too?’
>
>   ‘Maybe,’ said Hermione, shrugging, ‘or it might have Muggle-Repelling Charms on it, like the World Cup Stadium. And to keep foreign wizards from finding it, they’ll have made it Unplottable –’*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire: — CHAPTER ELEVEN —
>    
>   Aboard the Hogwarts Express</sup></sub>

We see how these work earlier in the book.

> *‘Seats a hundred thousand,’ said Mr Weasley, spotting the awestruck
>   look on Harry’s face. ‘Ministry task force of five hundred have been
>   working on it all year. Muggle-Repelling Charms on every inch of it.
>   Every time Muggles have got anywhere near here all year, they’ve
>   suddenly remembered urgent appointments and had to dash away again …
>   Bless them,’ he added fondly, leading the way towards the nearest
>   entrance, which was already surrounded by a swarm of shouting witches
>   and wizards.*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire: — CHAPTER EIGHT — The Quidditch
>   World Cup</sup></sub>

Comment: As an amateur photographer, if I saw a mouldering ruin with a sign saying *Danger, Do not enter, unsafe* I'd be planning what sort of "Ruin Porn" shots I could get and how I could get into it. (I once climbed the wall of a 13th century castle and climbed in a window in order to get past the bars on the main gate so I could take pics)

Comment: I would presume that the fact that Hogwarts has its "look like a ruin disguise" that it *does not* have Muggle-repelling charms.

Comment: @PeterM - You would "*suddenly remember [an] urgent appointment [and] dash away*"

Comment: Thank you! I wonder what the charm does! Would it just stop them from getting in or would it do something really cool like turn them into a wrackwort?

Comment: @Hewhoshallnotbenamed - It just makes them leave.

Comment: @Valorum Exactly. Wrackworts have leaves, yes?

Comment: @MattGutting - Like the proverbial panda?

Comment: @Valorum Which makes me wonder by what legal theory does the wizarding world work under that gives them unrestrained power to mess with my very being.  Although I'm sure there is already a question about that subject on here.

Comment: @PeterM - http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/File:Magic_is_Might_Monument.jpg

Comment: @Valorum Ah I see.  They do because they can.  So wizards are inherently bullies?

Comment: @PeterM I wouldn't say *inherently*. Just *usually*.

Comment: If they had Muggle-repelling charms then what would be the point of having the sign? The Muggles would never get close enough to read it...